# How to drop rows from Dataframe where values in 2 columns are the sam?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

My DF looks like below

```
Date   New_date X  Y
01-12  01-12    3  4
01-13  01-13    6  1
01-14  01.15    2  3
```

I need this result:

```
Date   New_date X  Y
01-14  01.15    2  3
```

o code should remove first 2 rows because values in columns Date and New_date are the same. I tried with this:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['Date'] == df['New_date']])
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Best regards and thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change logic - get all rows if not equal values.

So change `==` to `!=` for not equal values and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Date'] != df['New_date']]
print (df)
    Date New_date  X  Y
2  01-14    01.15  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'New_date'], keep=False)
```